# Run Instruments and Debug Console simultaneously

Tags: iphone, xcode, console-application, instruments

How can I make an app "Run with performance tool" and at the same time Run the Debug Console in XCode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "Console" application on the mac itself. Any `NSLog` and several types of warnings/errors will show up in the "Console messages" section.

This is of course just logging, interactive debugging is not an option.

Answer (score -1):

Just show the debug console  + MAJ + r or simply go to XCode preferences, Debuging section and set Show console on start.

Comment: False. When running app within Instruments - Xcode debugger is not being launched.